# Transfer reminders from iCal to Google Calendar

Tags: ical, calendar, google-calendar, caldav

I switched from iCloud to Google calendar. I already transferred all my calendars via export/import to Google Calendar. Now I'd like to transfer my reminders from iCal/iCloud to Google Calendar. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, Reminders are not transferrable. Each service programs them differently and there is no way (other than copying/pasting text) to easily transfer them. Hope this helps.

Comment: I hope you are wrong but after doing some more research I guess you are unfortunately right.

Answer (score 0):

This script will at least help with the export from Reminders:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "Reminders"
    set todo_accounts to every account
    -- accounts have lists. loop thru accounts to get their lists.
    repeat with i from 1 to length of todo_accounts
        tell account i
            set todo_lists to get every list
            -- lists have reminders. loop thru lists to get their reminders
            repeat with j from 1 to length of todo_lists
                tell list j
                    set todos to (get reminders)
                    -- if there are no reminders for a list, then ignore the list
                    if length of todos is greater than 0 then
                        -- Write out the name of the list
                        do shell script "echo " & (quoted form of (get name)) & " >> ~/Desktop/todos.txt"
                        -- loop thru the reminders to get properties
                        repeat with k from 1 to length of todos
                            set this_todo to item k of todos
                            if (this_todo is not completed) then
                                do shell script "echo [  ] " & (quoted form of (get name of this_todo)) & " >> ~/Desktop/todos.txt"
                            end if
                        end repeat
                    end if
                end tell
            end repeat
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Paste that into Apple Script and run